# JSON never a valid return type. Not even tutorial code

Tags: json, google-apps-script

So I've been at this for many hours. I'm creating a JSON export script that generates a JSON object from a sheet to be used by another web app.

No matter how I return it, it will always, 100% of the time, tell me the following:

```
The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type.
```

Even by just copy pasting tutorial code, [like the following](https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2016/04/14/how-to-serve-json-using-the-google-apps-script-content-service/), or as below:

```
var myDog = {"name": "Rhino", "breed": "pug", "age": 8}

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myDog);

function doGet(request){

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(myJSON).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

}
```

It will always return me this error. Strangely, clicking the test button returns the entire object just fine in all cases..

Comment: In your web app URL, replace /exec with /dev to always test the latest version of your code. Once you are ready to deploy, go to Publish -> Deploy as a web app.. and publish the most recent changes

Comment: @AntonDementiev. Thanks, it seems that updating an existing version is bugged, new one made it work fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script looks good. Make sure you have published a new version of the web app after changing the code.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the "update" functionality is broken. I tried to republish under an old version, but it fails to overwrite it seems! New version made it work